# ProFTPd and SELinux: mkdir Permission denied

Tags: centos, permissions, nfs, selinux, ftp

I have a ProFTPd server on Centos 6.3 with SELinux Enforcing.  My users are virtual users in a flat file.  The users are chrooted to directories mounted via NFS.  I've already set the following policy:

```
/usr/sbin/semanage boolean -m --on allow_ftpd_use_nfs
/usr/sbin/semanage boolean -m --on allow_ftpd_anon_write
```

The users can read and write files without problem.  However, they cannot create directories.  I get this in audit.log:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1364763704.972:25268): avc:  denied  { create } for  pid=2971 comm="proftpd" name="test4" scontext=system_u:system_r:ftpd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0 tclass=dir
```

Is there away to keep SELinux on but allow directory creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a policy error. Try adding this policy by doing the following..

1. Create a new directory called "localftpd"
2. Place the content below into a file called "localftpd.te" inside of this new directory.
3. Run `make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile load`

This is the policy amendment you need.

```
policy_module(localftpd, 1.0.0)

require {
    type ftpd_t;
    type nfs_t;
}

tunable_policy(`allow_ftpd_use_nfs && allow_ftpd_anon_write', `
    create_dirs_pattern(ftpd_t, nfs_t, nfs_t)
    delete_dirs_pattern(ftpd_t, nfs_t, nfs_t)
    rename_dirs_pattern(ftpd_t, nfs_t, nfs_t)
');
```

Comment: awesome, that totally worked.  Thanks!  It also got me to start learning this custom module business.

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this, I needed to make some changes to make this work, but the above answer led me on the right path:
tunable_policy(`allow_ftpd_use_nfs && allow_ftpd_anon_write', `
    fs_manage_nfs_files(ftpd_t)
    fs_manage_nfs_dirs(ftpd_t)
');